# how to decrement a part in a value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

i have an array in the format

```
array() {["2011-07-29"]=> 39 ["2011-07-30"]=> 39 ["2011-07-31"]=> 39 ["2011-08-01"]=> 40}
```

i need t0 decrement the middle keyvalue by 1 i.e ["2011-***07***-29"] to ["2011-***06***-29"]

the output should be

```
array() {["2011-06-29"]=> 39 ["2011-06-30"]=> 39 ["2011-06-31"]=> 39 ["2011-07-01"]=> 40}
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Like Fernaref explained: Change the keys according to your needs by parsing their value. There are multiple ways to accomplish that, this is just one example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/4S58WE6Q)):

```
<?php

$data = array(
  '2011-07-29' => 39,
  '2011-07-30' => 39,
  '2011-07-31' => 39,
  '2011-08-01' => 40,
);

$keys = array_keys($data);

foreach($keys as &$key)
{
    list(,$month) = sscanf($key, '%d-%d-%d');
    $month = sprintf("%02d", $month-1);
    $key[5] = $month[0];
    $key[6] = $month[1];
}
unset($key);

$data = array_combine($keys, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Nice trick using substr to pad the month number. I'll have to remember that one!

Comment: @Flambino: Actually I was too lazy too lookup the sprintf notation for it, that's far better: `$month = sprintf("%02d", $month-1);` - edited (but thanks for the feedback :) ).

Comment: @hakre: I was too lazy as well, so I used str_pad in my answer :P -- and sure sprintf is the right tool, but that isn't as fun as repurposing substr :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a string - you'll have to parse the data out, decrement the value and put the key back together. Or use a better key in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  $newKey = someFunction($key);
  $newArray[$newKey] = $value;
}
```

While "someFunction" will convert your date to create the new key

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  $date = strtotime ($key);

  $result[date("Y-m-d", strtotime("- month", $date)] = $val;
}
```

Comment: -1, does not work for me. `-1 month` or you reduce the array to one key only and additionally, if the key is not a valid date to do the substraction on, it will get removed/overwritten. Compare: http://codepad.org/4ACdinyA

Answer (score 0):

somefunction can be

```
preg_replace("@(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)@e","'\$1-'.str_pad($2-1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)",$key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array("2011-07-29"=>39, "2011-07-30"=>39, "2011-07-31"=>39, "2011-08-01"=>40);
$output = array();

foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    $key = preg_replace_callback("/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-/", function($match) {
        $match[2] = (int) $match[2] - 1;
        if( $match[2] < 1 ) { // don't forget to decrement the year, if the month goes below 1
            $match[1] = (int) $match[1] - 1;
            $match[2] = 12;
        }
        return $match[1] . "-" . str_pad($match[2], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-";
    }, $key);
    $output[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($output);
```